# Is there a way to use a delegate/action to generate a Kendo Grid's columns?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ExpenseClaimHeader>()
        .Name("Manage-Expense-Type-grid")

    .Columns(columns.Bound(o => o.FromDate).Title("From Date").Width(230);
        columns.Bound(o => o.ToDate).Title("To Date").Width(230);
    })
}
```

I would like to generate the columns depending on the state of the View that it is in. I have a model that passes in a state of the view and depending on that, I would like to add and remove columns.

What is the best way of doing this?

I am trying to see if I can create a delegate somehow as the Columns() seems to be taking an Action?

```
Columns(System.Action<Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridColumnFactory<T>>)
```

How would I create this in the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a column to any property (preferably a record ID) and display whatever you want using ClientTemplate:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.Id).ClientTemplate("#={ ... }#");
```

If you would like to display columns conditionally just enclose columns.Bound() in an if statement, so it'd look like that:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ExpenseClaimHeader>()
   .Name("Manage-Expense-Type-grid")
   if({condition}) {
      .Columns(columns.Bound(o => o.FromDate).Title("From Date").Width(230);
   }
)
```